# Understanding bitshift error from C to MatLab

Tags: c, matlab, bit-shift

I'm trying to create a function that uses the `bitshift` operation, this function I'm creating comes from C code that is working correctly. The problem that is happening is that it works for only a few values. Debugging the two functions (MatLab and C) I realize that in the `bitshift` operation is the problem, in C the value is`27` and MatLab gets `378`. Below are the two functions, the C code is with `printf()` calls to see the values after every line, in MatLab I used own debug.

C:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned char value = 189;
  printf("\nValue: %d",value);
  signed char temp,temp2;
  // cast to signed value
  temp = (signed char) value;
  // if MSB is 1, then this will signed extend and fill the temp variable with 1's
  printf("\nTemp signed:%d",temp);
  temp = temp >> 7;
  // AND with the reduction variable
  printf("\nTemp << 7: %d",temp);
  temp = temp & 0x1b;
  printf("\nTemp and: %d",temp);
  temp2 = value<<1;
  printf("\nValue << 1: %d");
  // finally shift and reduce the value
  printf("\nGalois Value: %d", (temp2^temp));
}
```

MatLab:

```
value = uint16(189);
hex = uint16(hex2dec('1B')); 
temp = typecast(value, 'int8');
temp = bitshift(temp,-7); 
temp = bitand(typecast(temp,'uint16'),hex); 
temp2 = bitshift(value,1);
galois_value =  bitxor(temp2,uint16(temp)); 
disp(galois_value);
```

Some input values I'm using to test it:

```
48,105,189,112,182,97,96,78,98,236,51,5,5,183,248,231,149,145,248,170,86,143,134,31,186,94,226,64,181,207,64,51,15,119,113,130
```

With this values the output expected is (from the C code):

```
96,210,97,224,119,194,192,156,196,195,102,10,10,117,235,213,49,57,235,79,172,5,23,62,111,188,223,128,113,133,128,102,30,238,226,31
```

But I get this values from matlab code:

```
  96,210,353,224,375,194,192,156,196,451,102,10,10,373,491,469,305,313,491,335,172,261,279,62,367,188,479,128,369,389,128,102,30,238,226,287
```

Basically what is going wrong: after my `bitshift(value,1)` in operation `temp2` should be equal `27` (the hexdecimal value), but this value is getting `378`. Debugging the C code I understood that the `temp2` variable should be equal `27` everytime that the `temp >> 7` operaton is equal `-1`, when the result of the `temp >> 7` operation is equal `0` the value of `temp2` should be `0` too, for this situation (`temp >> 7` operation equal 0) the function in MatLab is working, but when this get equal `-1` the `bitshift` gets a wrong value.

Someone knows how to fix that?

Comment: You have various implementation defined and (potentially) undefined behaviour in your code. In general shifting signed integers in C is a bad idea for exactly those reasons. Also read [ask] and follow the advice. "Does not work" is not a valid problem description!

Comment: @Toby: You cannot shift 8 bit numbers. `int` is **at least** 16 bits. (And `char` is not necessarily 8 bits).

Comment: @Olaf I've updated my question to show exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Matlab code has exactly same results as the C code I provided next.

```
input_array = [48,105,189,112,182,97,96,78,98,236,51,5,5];
for (i = 1:length(input_array))
    value = uint8(input_array(i));
    temp = typecast(value, 'int8');
    temp = bitshift(temp,-7); 
    hex = int8(hex2dec('1B')); 
    temp = bitand(temp,hex); 
    temp2 = typecast(bitshift(value,1),'int8');
    galois_value =  typecast(bitxor(temp2,temp),'uint8'); 
    disp(galois_value);
end
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char input_array[] = { 48, 105, 189, 112, 182, 97, 96, 78, 98, 236, 51, 5, 5 };
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char value = input_array[i];
        //printf("\nValue: %d", value);
        signed char temp, temp2;
        // cast to signed value
        temp = (signed char)value;
        // if MSB is 1, then this will signed extend and fill the temp variable with 1's
        //printf("\nTemp signed:%d", temp);
        temp = temp >> 7;
        // AND with the reduction variable
        //printf("\nTemp << 7: %d", temp);
        temp = temp & 0x1b;
        //printf("\nTemp and: %d", temp);
        temp2 = value << 1;
        //printf("\nValue << 1: %d");
        // finally shift and reduce the value
        printf("\nGalois Value: %d", unsigned char(temp2^temp));
        //printf("\n done");
    }
    printf("\n done");
}
```

Output in both cases is: 
 96   210   97  224  119  194  192  156  196  195  102   10   10

Comment: Now works only for the value `189`, I'm going to update the question to show you.

Comment: In second to last line I used: `typecast(bitxor(temp2,temp),'uint8')`